# How to store a split string as an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to take input from the user as part of a text-based adventure game. The input from the user can only be 2 words, a verb and a noun, and I want to split the string input into 2 words using the split() method and store that as a string array.

Here is some of the code:

```
in = input.nextLine();

inArray = Arrays.toString(in.split(" ", 2));
```

I get an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]"

How do I split a string and store it as a string array?

Comment: You're converting the array to string with `Arrays.toString(...)` . Remove that and just do `in.split(" ", 2)`

Comment: I tried it that way, but if I try to print out the array to the console, it just says "[Ljava.lang.String;@214c265e"

Comment: Then wrap it in `Arrays.toString(...)` when you're printing (i.e. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inArray));` and keep your `inArray = in.split(" ", 2);`

Comment: @Christilyn Yes, or with `Arrays.asList(inArray))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in.split(" ", 2)` creates an array of `String` elements. Arrays don't generally print easily. Using `Arrays.toString()` is a good way to get a nice **`String`** representation of the array object. If you want to store the array object, use the result of `in.split(" ", 2)`, and format it as a string only when you need to.